# How does one remove internal borders for specified cells with Pandas Styler?

Tags: python, css, pandas, border, pandas-styles

I would like to add borders to specific cells and when adjacent, border the adjacent group without internal borders.

Here is my code so far...

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"TransNo":[29, 32, 34, 45, 68, 71, 72, 73, 81],
                    "Type":["Fee", "Sale", "Fee", "Fee", "Sale", "Sale", "Sale", "Sale", "Fee"],
                  "Amount": [1.2, 10.2, 2.1, 3.1, 15.3, 19.2, 100.5, 97.3, 2.2]})

def border(cell_value):
    if cell_value == "Sale":
        return "border: solid thin"
    
df.style.applymap(border)
```

and here is the output...

[image: Output]

and here is the markup of the desired output...

[image: Desired]

The red markup indicating the deletion of internal borders.

Comment: Try this blog post on [Pandas styling](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/06/style-your-pandas-dataframe-and-make-it-stunning/)

Comment: I think you're going to have to use selectors to remove those "internal" borders.   I dont think there is a way to programmatically select those borders.

Answer (score 0):

A very *basic/naïve* approach would be to not draw those internal borders from the beginning.

```
#feel free to adjust the size/style of the borders

def outer_border(ser):
    m1 = ser.eq("Sale")
    m2 = ser.shift(-1).eq("Sale")
    m3 = ser.shift(+1).eq("Sale")
    conds = [m1 & ~m2 & ~m3, #isolated,
             m2 & m3, #surrounded,
             m1 & m2 & ~m3, #headed
             m1 & ~m2 & m3 #tailed
    ]
    
    vals = ["border: 4px solid",
            "border-left: 4px solid;border-right: 4px solid",
            "border-top: 4px solid;border-left: 4px solid;border-right: 4px solid",
            "border-bottom: 4px solid;border-left: 4px solid;border-right: 4px solid"
    ]

    return np.select(conds, vals, default="")

df.style.apply(outer_border, subset="Type")
```

Output :

[image]